# Battlefront 2 (2005) Campaign - Completing the Hoth mission

Tags: cheats, star-wars-battlefront-2

Soo I recently bought the version of Battlefront 2 (the good one) that got ported to PC, and have been working through the campaign. I'm currently up to the Hoth mission, specifically the final aspect, where you have to place a gathering beacon, and defend it for a minute to complete the mission. Has anyone actually competed this part, or is it impossible? Every time, i manage to plant the beacon, but then what seems like the entire Rebel team starts throwing grenades at it, and I cannot defend said beacon, because I keep getting killed by autoturrets and the like.

Does anyone have any ideas, cheats or relevant experience on the matter? Or is it just luck?

Comment: I did it so it's surely feasable, I'm not an especially good player. I remember the grenading being a big problem, I would recommend razing the zone to the ground before setting your beacon.

Comment: Nevermind, I just completed it, it just took a while.